# React-semantic-ui with route errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a basic menu imported from react semantic-ui

```js
<Menu secondary vertical>
        <Menu.Item
          name='account'
          active={activeItem === 'account'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        />
```

I obviously have more items and I modified such that each item from the menu links to a different page:

```js
<Menu secondary vertical>
         <Link to="/account">
         <Menu.Item
          name='account'
          active={activeItem === 'account'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        />
        </Link>
```

The code obviously works as expected however I am getting the error

```
<a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>
```

So I modified the code to `<Menu.item as='div'` and it still works however it loses some functionalities. Basically before I was able to hover on the menu item and it would show the result in the picture. To get on "account" the same result, I have to click twice. If I leave Menu.item as 'a' it works. 
Any way I could fix that? 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbYCR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using Link and Menu.Item like that.

You could do something similar to what you already did with as property. You could say

```
<Menu.Item 
   as={Link}
   to={"/account"}
   name='account'
   active={activeItem === 'account'}
   onClick={this.handleItemClick}
>
    Account
</Menu.Item>
```

This means you need to import {Link} from react-router-dom which I suppose you already did

Comment: Can I find out why was my answer down voted since it is perfectly functioning in the projects that I am making with react semantic ui?

Comment: It works for me as well. Thanks for sharing. I didn't downvote, I can't upvote either since my account is brand new

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (if you do not need anchor tag for some reason) is to handle it in method handleItemclick:

```js
handleItemClick = (e) => {
  //..code
  this.props.history.push('/myroute');
}
```

Comment: he does not need anchor tag. Menu.Item is anchor tag if you look at the DOM structure.

Comment: @LazarNikolic his problem indeed is that both Link and Menu.Item render as anchor. If he want a fast solution and avoid css adjustment this will work fine without using <Link />

Comment: @LazarNikolic your solution is valid, too

Comment: Thanks, I consider it